# send image between views using prepareForSegue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, storyboard, segue

I am working on an Iphone application using storyboard.

I have a button in a view (SelectionViewController) and when the user clicks on the button, it goes to another view (ImagesResultsViewController) (.

What I need is to send an image from the first view to the second. for that I named the segue identifier "resultViewSegue" and used the prepareForSeague method to get reference to the destination view and place the image in a UIImage view on it:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //if the segue identifier is "resultViewSegue"
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"resultViewSegue"])
    {
        //get the destination view which is ImagesResultsViewController
        ImagesResultsViewController * destinationView = segue.destinationViewController;

        //Set the image in the UIImageView
        [destinationView.mainImageView setImage:myImageToSend];
        //mainImageView is a UIImageView in the "ImagesResultsViewController" I created a property for it and synthesize it
    }
}
```

However the image was not set. after debugging I found out that the `destinationView.mainImageView` is  null. How can I get a reference of the UIImageView and set its picture from the segue?

Thank a lot for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a UIImage property in the ImagesResultsViewController
In the prepareForSegue method set it to the image you want and then in the viewdidload 
set it in the UIImageView